# Get value of Input type text in VB Code

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I have this control in ASP:

```
   <input type="text"  id="datepicker" name="datepicker" runat="server">
```

There's a JQuery function related to it

I want to get the value in the input text **in my VB code,** so I used this

> ```
>  Dim VALUE As String
>  VALUE = Request.Form("datepicker")
> ```

But it's not working.

I am getting VALUE is nothing

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If your VB code show above is the code behind of your asp page, then you dont need to use `Request.Form` unless your trying to access from remote html form

Comment: are you posting back to the same page or another page? if you are using runat="server" you should be directly able to access the textbox using the id

Comment: @dreamweiver When I write VALUE=datepicker.text , I get the error "text is not a member of System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText"

Comment: @HelpASisterOut see my answer below, it should be `datepicker.Value` instead of `datepicker.Text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the TextBox object in your code behind - because it has a `runat="server"` tag the code can see it:

```
Dim VALUE As String
VALUE = datepicker.text
```

**EDIT**

Apologies, just saw you're using a HTML `<input />`, rather than a `<asp:TextBox />` control. However, the `runat="server"` should mean your codebehind can still access the object but the `.text` may not be available... You may need `.value` or `.ToString`

Comment: When I write VALUE=datepicker.text , I get the error "text is not a member of System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText"

Comment: As said in my edit, should be `.Value` - Although, you would normally use `<asp:textbox ` which has `.Text` as a member

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
VALUE = Request.Form("datepicker")(0)
```

because `Request.Form` is a Collection.

Also, because of the runat="server" part, your input is visible server side, so this works too:

```
VALUE = datepicker.Value
```

Comment: When I write VALUE=datepicker.text , I get the error "text is not a member of System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText"

Answer (score 1):

Since `datepicker` has `runat="server"` property, you can get the value this way:

```
 Dim VALUE As String
 VALUE = datepicker.Value
```